# for what value(s) of $x$ is $nx$ congruent to $1 \pmod {(n+1)}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

I need to find some fixed integer value for $x$ which satisfies $ nx \equiv 1 \pmod{ n+1} $.  This is for a midterm review and I dont really see how this is possible without using $n$ in the formula, which is forbidden.  Any help? thanks

Comment: Have you thought about negative integers yet?

Comment: Hint: $n\equiv -1\pmod{n+1}$

Comment: Ahh, I thought i had tried that but I guess i was doing it wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$n+1\equiv 0 \ ( \textrm{mod } (n+1)  )$

$nx+x\equiv 0 \ ( \textrm{mod } (n+1)  )$

$nx\equiv -x \ ( \textrm{mod } (n+1)  )$

So you need that $-x\equiv 1 \ ( \textrm{mod } (n+1)  )$, which means  $x\equiv -1 \ ( \textrm{mod } (n+1)  )$. In conclusion, the values of $x$ you want are $\{(n+1)k-1: \ k\in\mathbb{Z} \}$.